# How to print PHP syntax in HTML

Tags: php, html

I dont know the correct syntax to print out the values from the database after the Get values button is submitted without getting the Invalid argument supplied error.. please help

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="User Name">
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit">
<input type="submit" name='seeDatabase' value="Get Values">
</form>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>User_Name   </th>
    <th>First_Name  </th>
    <th>Email</th>
</tr>
<?php
$sqlSelect = "Select * From user";
$myResult2 = $connection->query($sqlSelect);
foreach ($myResult2 as $item): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $item['user_name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['first_name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['email'] ?></td>
    <td>
        <form action="delete.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="userName" value="<?php echo                      
      $item['user_name']  ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do? you alredy printed database value inside HTML `value="<?php echo    $item['user_name']  ?>"`

Comment: I would like to do data checking with the isset() function and not have any of the information printed until button with the value of "get Values" is clicked on.   I usually do it with and if statement and put all the code needed in that statement, but when i do that it causes problems with the html code.  This is an example of what im trying to accomplish

Comment: <?php
    if(isset($_POST['seeDatabase']))
    {
    $sqlSelect = "Select * From user";
    $myResult2 = $connection->query($sqlSelect);
    foreach ($myResult2 as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item['user_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['first_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['email'] ?></td>
            <td>

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the array is empty before looping to prevent getting the invalid argument error

```
if(!empty($myResult2) && count($myResult2) > 0) {
//you can loop over 
foreach ($myResult2 as $item) {
//foreach stuff
}
} else {
//array is empty 
echo 'no result found';
}
```